# OpenEdge Progress 10.2B calling webservice - Error 5486 "Transport Resources Unavailable"

Tags: web-services, progress-4gl, openedge

I'm calling a Webservice sending a big XML through a LONGCHAR variable that is filled by Dataset using method WRITE-XML().

After calling the WS 1400 times (70000 rows broken by groups of 50), Progress returned error 5486. After some Google research, I've found [this](http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/Transport-resources-unavailable-5486-and-Unable-to-connect-to-NameServer-at-Host-10-133-249-148-Port-5013-8235-when-operating-system-out-of-memory) and [this](http://tdn.totvs.com/pages/releaseview.action;jsessionid=F418E27B4D591A57408DFBD386D8BB4E?pageId=5271724). It seems that Progress is not freeing memory or the ports used to connect the WS.

The call is made this way:

```
                DEF VAR hGenericWs AS HANDLE NO-UNDO.
                DEF VAR hGenericPort AS HANDLE NO-UNDO.
                DEF VAR cUrlWS AS CHAR NO-UNDO.
                DEF VAR cHeaderMethod AS CHAR NO-UNDO.
                DEF VAR cTransactionMethod AS CHAR NO-UNDO.
                DEF VAR cNamespace AS CHAR NO-UNDO.
                DEF VAR cPort AS CHAR NO-UNDO.

                RUN getGenericWsHandles IN h-dbapi072(OUTPUT cPort,
                                                      OUTPUT cNamespace,
                                                      OUTPUT cTransactionMethod,
                                                      OUTPUT cHeaderMethod,
                                                      OUTPUT cUrlWs).

                CREATE SERVER hGenericWs. 
                IF cUrlWs <> '' THEN
                    hGenericWs:CONNECT("-WSDL " + cUrlWs) NO-ERROR.
                IF NOT hGenericWs:CONNECTED() THEN DO:
                    /*show message error*/
                END.
                ELSE
                DO:
                    RUN value(cPort) SET hGenericPort ON hGenericWs NO-ERROR.
                end.
                /*send data to webservice*/
                /*free hGenericPort, disconnect and free hGenericWS and reallocate both after 40.000 calls*/
                FINALLY:
                    IF VALID-HANDLE(hGenericWs) THEN DO:
                        hGenericWs:DISCONNECT().
                        DELETE OBJECT hGenericWs.
                    END.
                    IF VALID-HANDLE(hGenericPort) THEN
                    DO:
                        DELETE OBJECT hGenericPort.
                    END.
                END FINALLY.
```

Does anyone dealed with it?

UPDATE: now I free the variables of Interal WS Port and the Webservice Handle after 8.00 calls to WS (40.000 rows broken by amounts of 50)

Comment: Without looking in to your code too much: do you delete everything you create (apart from records). Create server etc needs delete object...

Comment: "hGenericWS" and "hPort" I deleted just at the end of the process. It seems that, as the data to be sent is huge, the handles are consuming all WebService port numbers. I've tried to deleted and reallocate "hPort" for 3 times exactly, but I had no success

Comment: It could be failing sometimes and perhaps missing the cleanup then? You are not using any callbacks (set-callback-procedure)? Then you might also have to cleanup them?

Comment: I recall we had an issue once when calling a web service from within a web service on 10.2b that caused a memory leak. we had to work-a-round via a perl/curl script, but eventually there was a patch that fixed it.

Comment: @Jensd that's my hunch (Progress not freeing correctly). No, I'm not using any SET-CALLBACK-PROCEDURE. What would be the advantage to have one? And yes, I clean up the handles, after 800 calls to WS

Comment: @adejones how was this work-around? And what was the OpenEdge release patch you've applied? Which version?

Comment: What exact version are you on? Are there errors occuring sometimes perhaps thus making the cleanup not run?

Comment: @AndréLuísOliveira - sorry i don't have details (former job/company etc.) I just know when we made the call from within a progress webservice directly we had a memory leak that eventually (after many 1000s of calls) would bring the server down. so we made the call via shelling to OS and capturing response. This was 10.2b on windows. sorry don't know patch.

Comment: @Jensd 10.2B0837 . I'm trying to clean up hPort handle...until now no success

Comment: @adejones let me see if I understood. Instead of Progress call a WS, you've moved this call to be done by OS? So you changed the programming language that made the call?

Comment: @AndréLuísOliveira it was a perl script that called the desired web service. we passed params to it and captured/parsed the output. A bit of a pain, but avoided the memory leak we were encountering when we called directly from progress.

Comment: I've done some research and found this: knowledgebase.progress.com/.../000031099.

As I use dataset, XML and LOGNCHAR at my code, it seems a memory leak.

Has anyone seen it?

- See more at: https://community.progress.com/community_groups/openedge_general/f/26/p/29732/99717#99717